# Find the maximum value of $(xv-yu)^2$ subject to the constraints $x^2+y^2=1$ and $4u^2+8u+v^2=5$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This kind of question usually has a form $u^2+v^2=c$,then I can plug in the equation to calculate eigenvalues. But how can I deal with this form of the equation with u and v

Comment: $$9=5+4=4u^2+8u+v^2+4 = (2u+2)^2+v^2$$ So you can call $2u+2 = w$ and $u= \frac{w}{2}-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $A:=\frac{1}{2}|xv-yu|$ is the area of the triangle with vertices $O(0,0)$, $P(x,y)$, and $Q(u,v)$.  Because $|OP|=1$ always, we see that, or a fixed $Q$, the area $A$ is maximized if $OP\perp OQ$, and the maximum value of $A$ for this $Q$ is then $a(Q)=\frac{1}{2}|OQ|$.

> (This is an unnecessary observation.)  Note that the locus of $P$ is the unit circle, whereas the locus of $Q$ is the ellipse centered at $C(-1,0)$ with vertical major axis of length $6$ and horizontal minor axis of length $3$.

Therefore,
$$4\big(a(Q)\big)^2=|OQ|^2=u^2+v^2=u^2+\big(5-4u^2-8u\big)=\frac{31}{3}-\left(\frac{4}{3}+u\right)^2\leq \frac{31}{3}\,.$$
This means $(xv-yu)^2\leq \frac{31}{3}$.  The equality holds iff $(u,v,x,y)=\left(-\frac43,s\frac{\sqrt{77}}{3},st\frac{\sqrt{77}}{\sqrt{93}},t\frac{4}{\sqrt{93}}\right)$ with $s,t\in\{-1,+1\}$.

Comment: Thank you! But i want to use the method of Lagrange multiplier

Comment: Then, you should have specified that in your question.  And you should also show some of your work.

Comment: In fact, you can simply maximize $xv-yu$ in order to make life easy with Lagrange multipliers.  For any solution $(u,v,x,y)$, we have that $(u,v,-x,-y)$ is also a solution.